# Is it possible to make a function that modifies the input

Tags: python

```
makebbb(a):
    a = "bbb"
```

this function obviously fails to convert it's input to "bbb" as demonstrated by the following snippet

```
x = "notbbb"
makebbb(x)
print(x)
# Outputs "notbbb"
```

Now I understand the reason this fails, what I wish to find out is if there is anyway to make such a function? (I'm not just talking about assigning strings, but assignment with `=` in general)

Comment: read up on mutable and immutable arguments in python. you can not change immutable arguments. (you could hack your way around it by putting them in a list or declaring them global). there are many questions about just that here.

Comment: `def makebbb(a="bbb"):return a` than `print makebbb("test")`, Local initial value for changeable  or static variable

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable you want to change from a func as  `global` ,

```
>>> def makebbb():
    global x
    x = "bbb"


>>> print x
notbbb
>>> makebbb()
>>> print x
bbb
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply return a value in your function and update 'a'?

```
def makebbb(a):
    return "bbb"

x = "notbbb"
x = makebbb(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def makebbb(a):
    return "bbb"

x = "notbbb"
x = makebbb(x) #call function in the assignment to modify it 
print(x)
```

Output:

```
bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x` exists outside the scope of the function, you can modify the variable directly (*rebind values to the same variable in memory*). Otherwise, a functional approach would be to just return a new string.

```
x = "notbbb"
makebbb() # Modify variable outside function scope.
print(x)
```

or

```
x = "notbbb"
print(makebbb(x)) # return new value.
```

The particular catch with this example is that you are trying to pass a an **immutable** value by reference. What happens instead is that a copy is created on argument passing. You can achieve the effect you want with **mutable** types such as lists though.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify *some* arguments, those that are passed by reference instead of by value.

Arguments that are *mutable objects* can be changed, like so:

```
def change_list(l):
    l.append(4)

k = [1, 2, 3]
change_list(k)
print(k)   # Prints [1,2,3,4]
```

This, however, will not work:

```
def dont_change_list(l):
    l = [5]
```